# Is return autorelease a bug in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

I am new to objective c and am trying to understand how/when autorelease is called. I understand the simple use case of:

```
- (void) foo {
    Bar *b = [[[Bar alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self doSomething:b];
  }
```

What about this next case -- is this a bug, because the object will be immediately released upon leaving the scope of makeBar?

```
-(Bar*) makeBar
{
    return [[[Bar alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

What if the caller does a retain?

```
Bar *b = [[self makeBar] retain];
```

Thanks,
-Eric

Comment: This contents of this question and the two answers below should be on the required reading list for those new to ObjC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your second example, the anonymous object you're returning will not be released as soon as the execution leaves the scope of `makeBar` but on the next iteration of the run loop. This will give you the opportunity to `retain` it in whatever method has called `makeBar`

So your final example is ok since the retain count will not drop below 0.

Are you having trouble with it?

Comment: To be more specific, it will be released when the autorelease pool that it was added to is drained/released. This is typically at the end of a run loop, but not always.

Comment: No problems, I've just been scanning my code for potential memory issues and saw that pattern from sample code I had copied and wasn't sure if it was a bug or not.

Answer (score 6):

```
-(Bar*) makeBar
{
    return [[[Bar alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

The 2nd case is the **preferred** way to return an Objective-C object. Except `+alloc`, `-copy...` and `-create...`, the method should retain no ownership of the returning object, i.e. the (change of) retain count should be 0.

However, `[[Bar alloc] init]` makes the object to have retainCount of +1, to one should release it before return. But `-release` will immediate deallocate the object, making the method useless. That's why `-autorelease` is used — it is a **delayed** `-release`, i.e. the object will be released eventually, but not now, so other parts of code can still interact with it, yet the retain count can still be balanced to 0.

---

```
Bar *b = [[self makeBar] retain];
```

You should *not* retain it *unless* you want to be a long-term owner of the object `b`.